# Laptops as a extended screen (not just mirror)

Tags: laptop, hdmi, vga

I have two laptops running Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

I want to extend my screen using my second laptop.

I am not talking about just mirror screen.

Hardware info:

both laptops have VGA and HDMI output
one of them has USB c port
Bluetooth available
both laptops have shared graphics
wifi connected (same network router)

VGA cable output to output won't work.Similarly on HDMI.

Using software like deskreen or network displays just mirrors.

Current I have only HDMI and VGA  and HDMI splitter cable

Comment: I do not think you can do that. BTW the bold in the middle of the question does not help. There is no version 20.4 I guess a typo? You also may want to read this https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yep Ubuntu has currently release a new long term version.. i am using 20.4 at time it was LTS. But any way work around with additional hardware?

Comment: You still did not write a valid version number there is no 20.4, there is an 20.04

Comment: Yep  David . I got now you actually referred to decimal point. I was just writing short . It is 20.04.  it is good to write to the specific points. Sorry about that

Comment: But any way work around with additional hardware if I buy like video capture cards to. Can these type hardware extended screen of laptops?

Comment: Hardware question make it off topic. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: And no, they can't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using typical recent laptops, it would be quite hard to do as they would have only 1 internal display connector ([LVDS or eDP](https://www.laptop-lcd-screen.co.uk/blog/post/2018/10/13/laptop-screen-signalling-interfaces-lvds-and-edp.aspx)).

For hardware able to drive an LVDS display, check for example this video *[What is LVDS ... Old laptop Screen reuse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gph9hYLPMFk)*.

You may instead be interested in using only one mouse/keyboard across your devices, which is enabled by software like Synergy and [more](https://www.makeuseof.com/best-apps-sharing-mouse-and-keyboard-across-computers/).